# Symfony tree configuration builder There is no extension able to load the configuration for

Tags: symfony

```
    $rootNode = $treeBuilder->root('payment_onpay');

    $rootNode
        ->children()
            ->arrayNode('configuration')
                ->children()
                    ->integerNode('client_id')->end()
                    ->scalarNode('client_secret')->end()
                ->end()
            ->end() // twitter
        ->end()
    ;
```

onpay.yml:

```
payment_onpay:
  configuration:
    client_id: "id"
    client_secret: "secret"
```

After running application throw exception:
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\InvalidArgumentException' with message 'There is no extension able to load the configuration for "payment_onpay" (in /var/public_html/game-server.loc/www/src/Payment/OnpayBundle/DependencyInjection/../Resources/config/onpay.yml). Looked for namespace "payment_onpay", found none' in /var/public_html/game-server.loc/www/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Loader/YamlFileLoader.php on line 356

Comment: Is your bundle added to your `AppKernel`?

Comment: So the key payment_onpay is not regonized. Why dont you tell us a bit more?

Comment: You may need to assure that your configuration is merged using a technique similar to that discussed [here](http://www.webtipblog.com/exposing-configuration-symfony-2-bundles/).

Comment: Maybe this config not used standalone? Sometimes you need to write configuration for a inherited component instead of this parent service? I faced same issue with configuring OroDataGridBudle in OroCRM